# Naming a business.

Tags: names, business-japanese

Can i call my therapeutic craft workshop Kokoro (Heart, mind, spirit?) or tsukuru(to make?) or Ukiyo (floating world, living in the moment?). I would like to make sure that there is no other (offensive or rude) meaning to any of these words. My favourite is Kokoro. Could you kindly advise me or maybe you have any other suggestions. Many thanks, Laura Martin UK

Comment: You should probably be aware that there is already a UK-based business called [kokoro](http://kokorouk.com/).

Comment: I think the words don't contain rude or offensive meaning. Ukiyo sounds a bit like art gallery (Japanese paintings). Interesting name though.

Comment: How about `iyashi / iyasu` (from 癒 that is also a bad-ass looking kanji that has a meaning of healing/cure etc) or `naoru` (from 治 that has similar meanings), or also `ikasu` (from 生かす that means "to make use of" but also "to let live/to revive". 生 itself has the meaning of "life/birth". On top of that ikasu can also mean "to be smart/cool)"
Out of your ideas, I also prefer kokoro,  while tsukuru is my least favorite (mostly just because does not make me think of anything therapeutic but merely to the act of making/creating/producing. If that's what you want of course is perfectly fine).

Answer (score 2):

I would say Kokoro and Tsukuru sound good, but Ukiyo sounds a little mysterious. I can see Kokoro is connected to therapeutic and Tsukuru is coming from craft or workshop, and these two can give us a kind and gentle impression. Ukiyo can be used in both a good and bad way. For instance, if you say Ukiyo-banare (an extraordinary life in both good and bad way) to somebody, one might feel that you are criticizing it. Ukiyo is a very difficult word to use even for Japanese people. I do not recommend you use it if you do not have any specific message that you would like to convey through this word.
I personally vote for Kokoro.